# Imprimir Cadena Aleatoria java

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse, cmd, jar

Estoy haciendo un programa de cadenas aleatorias para luego usarlas en el cmd con un metodo tuberia con otro proyecto, pero lo principal, es que a la hora de imprimir mi cadena, va imprimiendo caracter a caracter, es decir, si genero una cadena de 14 caracteres, imprime el primero, luego el segundo, y asi hasta los 14 caracteres. ¿Donde creeis que esta el problema? Gracias de antemano :)

[image: Ejecutando el programa]

````
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            System.out.println("¿Cuantas cadenas deseas ejecutar?");
            int repetir = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            if (repetir < 0) {
                System.out.println("Debes de introducir un numero positivo");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < repetir; ++i) {
                    int longitud = (int) (Math.random() * (22 - 1));
                    // El banco de caracteres
                    String cadenagrande = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                    // La cadena en donde iremos agregando un carácter aleatorio
                    String cadena = "";
                    for (int x = 0; x < longitud; x++) {
                        int indiceAleatorio = numeroAleatorioEnRango(0, cadenagrande.length() - 1);
                        char caracterAleatorio = cadenagrande.charAt(indiceAleatorio);
                        cadena += caracterAleatorio;
                        System.out.printf("Cadena aleatoria de"+ longitud + "caracteres: \n" + cadena);
                    }

                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
public static int numeroAleatorioEnRango(int minimo, int maximo) {
        // nextInt regresa en rango pero con límite superior exclusivo, por eso sumamos 1
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minimo, maximo + 1);

    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema es simplemente que tienes el `print` dentro del `for`. Mira a ver así:

```
                for (int x = 0; x < longitud; x++) {
                    int indiceAleatorio = numeroAleatorioEnRango(0, cadenagrande.length() - 1);
                    char caracterAleatorio = cadenagrande.charAt(indiceAleatorio);
                    cadena += caracterAleatorio;

                }
                    System.out.printf("Cadena aleatoria de"+ x + "caracteres: \n" + cadena);
```

Comment: Funcionó, se me paso por alto, muchisimas gracias

Comment: Me alegro. Márcame la respuesta porfa, que acabo de empezar en stackoverflow y me vienen bien los puntos ;D